# Using XML::Twig in Perl, how to add a parent to an existing element?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<element>
 <sub-element></sub-element>
 <sub-element></sub-element>
 <sub-element id="add_parent"></sub-element>
</element>
```

and I would like to add a parent to the node having the attribute "add_parent" so it would look like this:

```
<element>
 <sub-element></sub-element>
 <sub-element></sub-element>
 <new-parent>
  <sub-element id="add_parent"></sub-element>
 </new-parent>
</element>
```

I am using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) to select the correct element like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

$t->parsefile ('input.xml');
$v = $t->first_elt('[@id]');
```

which works fine and I would like to know if it is possible, to encapsulate the select element in a new element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, use the `wrap_in` method:

```
$v->wrap_in( 'new-parent');
```

Comment: sorry, I'm kind of a newbie in PERL and XML. Could spell out what I should put instead of 'foo' in your example?

Comment: I edited the answer now that you've added the name of the new element in your question